# How do I send my error in the chat and how do I send the output of my eval in an embed? Anything would help :)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, eval

Im currently making an eval command and im having trouble catching and logging the error aswell as sending the output of my command in an embed, any help would be appreciated!

```js
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}eval`)) {
    if(!message.author.id == "535235896530960395") return;
    var result = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
        let evaled = eval(result);
        const evalembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Input")
        .setDescription(result)
        .setFooter("AG Bot")
        .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send(evalembed)
        try {
        } catch (err) {
            message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${clean(err)}\n\`\`\``);
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why no error is being outputted is because your `try` loop isn't actually doing anything. You should have the code inside of the `try` loop that you want to run and if it fails then you can have the catch.

```js
    } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}eval`)) {
      try {
          if(!message.author.id == "535235896530960395") return;
            var result = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ")
            let evaled = eval(result);
            const evalembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Input")
            .setDescription(result)
            .setFooter("AG Bot")
            .setTimestamp()
            message.channel.send(evalembed)
        } catch (err) {
            message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${clean(err)}\n\`\`\``);
          }
        }
      });
```